# handle SIGBUS in linux

Tags: c, linux, signals

In one of my programs, I would hit "SIGBUS" when trying to access a mmap-ed memory location that failed to get the memory page (as the underlying physical memory ran out) and the program crashed due to SIGBUS.

I plan to register a SIGBUG signal handler to avoid crash. However, I don't want to exit() the program from the SIGBUS handler. I am trying to see if there is anyway to gracefully report ENOMEM and continue the program with other work.

Can I do the following? The code looks like this:

```
mem_p->head = MY_HEAD_MAGIC;   /* this line could trigger SIGBUS */
if (sigbus_happened) {
    sigbus_happened = FALSE;
    do_something_else();   
    return ENOMEM;
}
```

and the signal handler:

```
void signal_handler (int sig)
{
   if (sig == SIGBUS)
      sigbus_happened = TRUE;
}
```

Would the above work and no crash?

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: don't. Just make sure you don't address the mmapp()ed pages out-if-bounds, and don't rely on any trickery. Really.

Comment: @wildplasser If you use MAP_NORESERVE SIGBUS is possible when the system doesn't have enough memory+swap (although if you used all your swap you have bigger problems than the SIGBUS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the danger that the code you show could behave counter to your expectations. This is because the compiler is free to arrange the code so that it "remembers" the value of `sigbus_happened` before the assignment `mem_p->head`. So, even when the signal handler executes, your code may not detect that the flag has been set. At a minimum, you will need to make the variable `volatile`.

Better would be to simply check if the `mmap()` call failed. You do this by checking if the call returns the value `MAP_FAILED`. If the call failed, do not attempt to access the pointer value.

Your attempt to capture `SIGBUS` reminds of exception handling. C does not have C++ style exception handling (although, macro packages, such as [cexcept](http://www.nicemice.net/cexcept/), exist that mimic them). But, one way to follow your model in a way that is more like the way exceptions work would be to use `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`. `setjmp()` saves the existing stack context and returns `0`. `longjmp()` returns the code to the saved context, and causes `setjmp()` to return a non-`0` value.

From a signal handler, it is better to use the POSIX [`sigsetjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigsetjmp.html) and [`siglongjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/siglongjmp.html) so that any signals that were blocked by the C runtime or operating system just before calling the signal handler gets reset to the values they had upon returning to the saved context.

```
jmp_buf *sigbus_jmp; // global

void signal_handler (int sig)
{
   if (sig == SIGBUS) {
      if (sigbus_jmp) siglongjmp(*sigbus_jmp, 1);
      // no one to catch the error, so abort
      abort();
    }
}

    //...
    jmp_buf sigbus_jmpbuf;
    sigbus_jmp = &sigbus_jmpbuf;
    if (sigsetjmp(sigbus_jmpbuf, 1) == 0) {
        // try
        mem_p->head = MY_HEAD_MAGIC;   /* this line could trigger SIGBUS */
    } else {
        // catch
        do_something_else();   
        return ENOMEM;
    }
    sigbus_jmp = 0;
```

Comment: Better use [siglongjmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/siglongjmp.html) in a signal handler (with `sigsetjmp`)

Comment: Thank you jxh. I will try this method. By the way, my code already checks for mmap() failures and already handles that.  The problem is:  even mmap() succeeded, it is still possible that the memory access generates SIGBUS if the physical memory runs out or underlying tmpfs is full. In my understanding, mmap() does not guarantee the underlying physical memory always available. Is that right?

Comment: @user1783732: Use the `MAP_LOCKED` flag.

Comment: @jxh: wouldn't MAP_LOCKED be too expensive if the shared mem object size is big but initial content is very small?  Ideally we wanted to use similar-to-Copy-on-Write to save the actual physical memory.

Comment: You can choose to make sure your system has the memory you requested at the time you make the request, or you can let the system lie to you about the availability of the memory. If you know that eventually you need all of it, get all of it. If you are okay with using less, then ask for less.